# How to use libraries installed with a package manager in GNU/Linux

Tags: libraries, development

I installed a library(for example `lzma-dev`) using a package manager(for example `apt-get` for `Debian` or `Ubuntu`). How can I use it? Where can I find the `libs` and `headers`? How about `so`s(dynamic libraries)?

Comment: Essentially, any properly set-up distro will ensure that libraries installed via its package manager can be found in directories that are in the compiler's default search path. (Assuming that the compiler was likewise installed via the package manager)

Comment: @Shadur this means I can just `#include <header.h>`(for example for c++ libraries) and use it right along without having to think about adding library and include paths to the porject file, right?

Comment: In most cases, yes, although from the looks of @slm's the files will be at `/usr/include/<libname>` so the include directive you'll likely need would be `#include <libname/header.h>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the package has already been installed you can see the contents of it using `dpkg -L`, for list.

#### Example

```
$ dpkg -L lzma-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/lzma
/usr/include/lzma/LzHash.h
/usr/include/lzma/Types.h
/usr/include/lzma/LzmaEnc.h
/usr/include/lzma/LzFind.c
/usr/include/lzma/LzmaEnc.c
/usr/include/lzma/LzFind.h
/usr/include/lzma/LzmaDec.h
/usr/include/lzma/7zVersion.h
/usr/include/lzma/LzmaDec.c
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/lzma-dev
/usr/share/doc/lzma-dev/lzma.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/lzma-dev/Methods.txt
/usr/share/doc/lzma-dev/7zC.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/lzma-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/lzma-dev/7zFormat.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/lzma-dev/copyright
```

Packages that are named `<something>-dev` are typically just the C header files (`.h` files), this package is a bit unusual in that it includes (`.c` and `.h` files). Incidentally this is the actual source for the LZMA library.

If you want the `.so` files and the `.h` files for the LZMA library, so you can compile against it, you'll need to install the 'liblzma-dev` package.

#### Example

Here's the header files.

```
$ dpkg -L liblzma-dev | tail -15
/usr/include/lzma/version.h
/usr/include/lzma/hardware.h
/usr/include/lzma/index.h
/usr/include/lzma/index_hash.h
/usr/include/lzma/block.h
/usr/include/lzma/delta.h
/usr/include/lzma/check.h
/usr/include/lzma/filter.h
/usr/include/lzma/bcj.h
/usr/include/lzma/base.h
/usr/share/doc/liblzma-dev/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/liblzma-dev/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/liblzma-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/liblzma-dev/THANKS
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so
```

As well as the actual `.so` library:

```
$ dpkg -L liblzma5 | tail -4
/lib
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5
```

Comment: "and the .c and .h files for the LZMA library". The `.c` files are not packaged. They're source. Also, `.so` files are not part of a dev library, which just contain header files. The `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so` here is a symbolic link. It points to a file in the library package `liblzma5`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - take a look at the contents of lzma-dev, it does contain .c files.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - cleaned it up but this is a bit of a confusing example.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - 12.10, lzma-dev: 9.22-2ubuntu2

Answer (score 1):

```
dpkg -L lzma-dev
```

list all the files installed with apt-get for `lzma-dev`